# How to print list in pdf in different lines without brackets in Flutter?

Tags: pdf, flutter, dart

I have a class in Flutter with a method that returns a list of products and then I send that list to a pdf, but when I see the preview of the pdf, the list is displayed like this: [Product 1, Product2, Product 3], and what I want to achieve is to print that list in separate lines without the square brackets.

I'm just passing the list to another class, I can print it on the pdf but I want to print it without the square brackets in different lines.

This is my class with the method that returns the list:

```
class GetBotana {
  List<String> getProducts()
  {
    return listaProductos;
  }
}
```

And here is where I'm creating the pdf with the list:

```
pdf.addPage(pdfLib.Page(
pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
build: (pdfLib.Context context){
  return pdfLib.Center(
      child: pdfLib.ListView(
        children: <pdfLib.Widget>[
          pdfLib.Text(botana.getProducts().toString())
        ]
      )
    );
  }
)
```

);

The list is displayed like this: [Product 1, Product2, Product 3], and what I want to achieve is to print that list in separate lines without the square brackets, something like:

- Product 1
- Product 2
- Product 3

Answer (score -1):

You can use `forEach` to iterate and print over a list.

Example:

```
List<String> list =  List<String>();
list.add('one');
list.add('two');
list.add('twelve');
list.forEach((element) => print(element));

Output:

one
two
twelve
```

Comment: But how can I use a forEach to pass the list info to the pdf?

Comment: The answer does not serve the purpose